# Silex + form validation

Tags: php, forms, silex

I'm trying to create a simple form validation with [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). Since there is no official guide to the forms extension yet, I'm following the instructions on this site: http://dev.umpirsky.com/create-kick-ass-website-in-no-time-with-silex/

For some reason, the form won't validate correctly:

```
$form->isValid() // will always return true
```

I spent some time searching for a solution (of what seems to be a known issue), but haven't found anything useful.

Did someone else encounter this problem and knows a way around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a little bit more of your code? Just `$form->isValid()` does not say anything.

Comment: It's basically the same implementation like in here:
https://github.com/umpirsky/umpirsky.com/blob/master/src/app.php

Comment: This example does not contain validation rules. Silex form extension uses `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator`, so you must declare your own validation rules. Please see more of Silex [validator extension](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/validator.html)

Comment: I thought that by declaring form elements as required the validation would be added automatically...

Comment: No, that will only trigger client-side validation through the HTML5 required attribute. There's a nice example of validation in the Kitchen Sink though: https://github.com/lyrixx/Silex-Kitchen-Edition/blob/master/src/controllers.php#L17

Answer (score 4):

you probably missed to register the validator extension

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider(), array(
    'form.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/symfony/src'
));
$app->register(new Silex\Extension\ValidatorExtension(), array(
    'validator.class_path'    => __DIR__.'/vendor/symfony/src',
));
```

Comment: `form.class_path` is removed https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/FormServiceProvider.php#L88